# Swift: unable to create generic method for API call

Tags: swift, api, generics

I have the following API call which retrieves a list of airports and maps them to core data:

```
private func retrieveAirportsFromAPI() {
    API.client.call(.airports, expecting: [Airport].self) { (result, airports) in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Unable to retrieve airports")
        case .success:
            guard let airportResponse = airports else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for airport in airportResponse {
                    airport.mapToCoreData()
                }
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have a helper class for API calls and the call method is as follows:

```
public func call<R: Decodable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint,
                        with args: [String: String]? = nil,
                        using method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                        expecting response: R.Type?,
                        completion: APIResponse<R>) {
    call(endpoint, with: args, parameters: Nothing(),
         using: method, posting: Nothing(), expecting: response, completion: completion)
}
```

Now, I have several of these calls which are almost identical that I need to make - they just need to retrieve different objects, including Supplier and FuelType. So I was trying to make the method more generic so that I can inject the objects and endpoint when I call the methods.

So, I added a protocol:

```
protocol CoreDataMappable {
    func mapToCoreData()
}
```

And I made Airport, FuelType and Supplier conform to this protocol e.g.

```
class Airport: Codable, CoreDataMappable {
    var id: String
    let name: String?
    let iata3: String?
    let icao4: String?
    
    internal func mapToCoreData() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let storedAirport = AirportCD(context: context)
        
        storedAirport.id = self.id
        storedAirport.name = self.name ?? ""
        storedAirport.iata3 = self.iata3 ?? ""
        storedAirport.icao4 = self.icao4 ?? ""
    }
}
```

Then my plan was to inject the required elements like this:

```
    private func retrieveAirportsFromAPI<R: Decodable>(endpoint: Endpoint, object: R.Type?) {
    API.client.call(endpoint, expecting: [object].self) { (result, objects) in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Unable to retrieve airports")
        case .success:
            guard let objectResponse = objects else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for object in objectResponse {
                    if let mappableObject = object as CoreDataMappable {
                        object.mapToCoreData()
                    }
                }
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I get 2 errors here:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[R.Type?]' to expected argument type 'R.Type?'
Generic parameter 'R' could not be inferred
```

Wondering how I can get around this or if it is even possible. Copy and pasting this method with different objects each time seems pretty inefficient. I'm not sure why when the method is not generic I can add [Airport].self to the 'expecting' parameter, but [R.Type].self causes issues

UPDATE:

This is the full call method used in the helper class:

```
private func call<P: Encodable, B: Encodable, R: Decodable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint,
                                                            with args: [String: String]? = nil,
                                                            parameters params: P?,
                                                            using method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                                                            posting body: B?,
                                                            expecting responseType: R.Type?,
                                                            completion: APIResponse<R>) {

    // Prepare our URL components

    guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: baseURL.absoluteString) else {
        completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .invalidURL)), nil)
        return
    }

    guard let endpointPath = endpoint.url(with: args) else {
        completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .invalidURL)), nil)
        return
    }

    urlComponents.path = urlComponents.path.appending(endpointPath)

    // Apply our parameters

    applyParameters: if let parameters = try? params.asDictionary() {
        if parameters.count == 0 {
            break applyParameters
        }

        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let value = value as? String {
                let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
                queryItems.append(queryItem)
            }
        }

        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
    }

    // Try to build the URL, bad request if we can't

    guard let urlString = urlComponents.url?.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding,
        var url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .invalidURL)), nil)
            return
    }
    
    if let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString, endpoint.pattern == "/logging/v1/device/<device_id>" {
        let us = "http://192.168.6.128:3000/logging/v1/device/\(uuid)"
        guard let u = URL(string: us) else { return }
        url = u
    }

    // Can we call this method on this endpoint? If not, lets not try to continue

    guard endpoint.httpMethods.contains(method) else {
        completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .methodNotAllowed)), nil)
        return
    }
    
    // Apply debug cookie
    
    if let debugCookie = debugCookie {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(
            HTTPCookie.cookies(
                withResponseHeaderFields: ["Set-Cookie": debugCookie],
                for:url
        ), for: url, mainDocumentURL: url)
    }

    // Build our request

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if let headers = headers {
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }

    // If we are posting, safely retrieve the body and try to assign it to our request

    if !(body is NothingProtocol) {
        guard let body = body else {
            completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .buildingPayload)), nil)
            return
        }

        do {
            let result = try encode(body: body, type: endpoint.encodingType)
            request.httpBody = result.data
            request.setValue(result.headerValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        } catch {
            completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .buildingPayload)), nil)
            return
        }
    }
    
    // Build our response handler
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (rawData, response, error) in

        // Print some logs to help track requests
        
        var debugOutput = "URL\n\(url)\n\n"
        
        if !(params is Nothing.Type) {
            debugOutput.append(contentsOf: "PARAMETERS\n\(params.asJSONString() ?? "No Parameters")\n\n")
        }
        
        if !(body is Nothing.Type) {
            debugOutput.append(contentsOf: "BODY\n\(body.asJSONString() ?? "No Body")\n\n")
        }
        
        if let responseData = rawData {
            debugOutput.append(contentsOf: "RESPONSE\n\(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No Response Content")")
        }
        
        Logging.client.record(debugOutput, domain: .network, level: .debug)

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            guard error == nil else {
                completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .unwrappingResponse)), nil)
                return
            }

            completion?(.failure(nil, NetworkError(reason: .invalidResponseType)), nil)
            return
        }

        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        // We have an error, return it

        guard error == nil, NetworkManager.successStatusRange.contains(statusCode) else {
            var output: Any?

            if let data = rawData {
                output = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,
                                                            options: .allowFragments)) ?? "Unable to connect"
                
                Logging.client.record("Response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No error data")", domain: .network)
            }

            completion?(.failure(statusCode, NetworkError(reason: .requestFailed, json: output)), nil)
            return
        }

        // Safely cast the responseType we are expecting

        guard let responseType = responseType else {
            completion?(.failure(statusCode, NetworkError(reason: .castingToExpectedType)), nil)
            return
        }

        // If we are expecting nothing, return now (since we will have nothing!)

        if responseType is Nothing.Type {
            completion?(.success(statusCode), nil)
            return
        }

        guard let data = rawData else {
            assertionFailure("Could not cast data from payload when we passed pre-cast checks")
            return
        }

        // Decode the JSON and cast to our expected response type

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let responseObject = try decoder.decode(responseType, from: data)
            completion?(.success(statusCode), responseObject)
            return
        } catch let error {
            let content = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            Logging.client.record("Failed to build codable from JSON: \(String(describing: content))\n\nError: \(error)", domain: .network, level: .error)
            assertionFailure("Failed to build codable from JSON: \(error)")
            completion?(.failure(statusCode, NetworkError(reason: .castingToExpectedType)), nil)
            return
        }
    }

    // Submit our request

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: try this ```API.client.call(endpoint, expecting: object)```. You just need to pass the same type of object to call the API function, No need to create ```[object].self```

Comment: hmm, but in the response from the API I do receive an array of objects and then i need to decode these and run them through the for loop to map to core data

Comment: Yes but you already pass an array from ```retrieveAirportsFromAPI``` function.

Comment: doing this though then leaves me with: For-in loop requires 'R' to conform to 'Sequence'

Comment: Can you add a code for what you return as a result? inside call function. What you are returning in the completion handler.

Comment: It's pretty massive the call method - I've added it to the question. Ultimately, when I decode the object I do feel that expecting needs to be an array of the relevant type - at the moment if I remove the array and run the code, I just hit the failure instantly, whereas this works fine with [Airport].self

Comment: please check this: https://medium.com/@adoniscoder/using-swift-5-new-result-type-with-generics-40336dd2eb81

Comment: this sure is much cleaner thank you. However, unfortunately i am restricted because this call method is part of a library which is used by several applications and I am not able to edit it at the moment. So I am kind of stuck using it for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing the parameter `object` to the outer function, `R` becomes defined. So, you can use it with the inner `call` function

```
func retrieveFromAPI<R: Decodable>(endpoint: Endpoint, object: R.Type) {
   API.client.call(endpoint, expecting: R.self) { (result, objects) in

       //...
   }
}
```

But, if you further expect that the result will be an array of `R` objects conforming to `CoreDataMappable` in the response, then you'd need to constrain `R` and pass `[R].self` as the type to the `call` function:

```
func retrieveFromAPI<R: Decodable & CoreDataMappable>(endpoint: Endpoint, object: R.Type) {
   API.client.call(endpoint, expecting: [R].self) { (result, objects) in

       //...
   }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. So for me, yes I was expecting the result to be an array of CoreDataMappable objects, so I've gone with the second variation of your answer and it is working perfectly. Thank you